# How to change access to edit sequence

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want users to be able to edit a specific sequence. So I created a new manuitem:

```
<menuitem
    id="aimed_purchase_order_sequence" name="Sequence BCV"
    parent="purchase.menu_purchase_config" action="open_apo_sequence_form_view"/>
```

and this action:

```
<record id="open_apo_sequence_form_view" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Sequence Bons de commande</field>
    <field name="res_model">ir.sequence</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="res_id" ref="base.sequence_view_tree"/>
    <field name="domain">[('code','=','aimed.purchase.order')]</field>
</record>
```

This code gave me a tree view with a unique record. And I can't edit anything.
How can I make it load the form view and can actually edit it's values?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `form` instead of `tree`. Or for future use, if it's needed to edit more than one sequence use `tree,form` instead.

Comment: @CZoellner that solved my problem, which means this is not an access issue, it's a view type issue. Thanks. Create an answer if you want so I validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form instead of `tree`. Or for future use, if it's needed to edit more than one sequence use `tree,form` instead.

If you want to enable more than one view type, use commas like in my example `tree,form`. Important: don't uses spaces.